# Is it possible to remove a property from a java object at run time?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a pojo with jpa anntations.  One of the string properties is marked as not nullable.  There is some code downstream which sets the value if it is not set. In certain cases this code needs to be triggered but if set the value to empty string this is treaded as a value and its not triggered.  I can't set the non null value to null and so I can't edit theobject to trigger the code in a conventional way.

To be honest this bit of code needs a refactoring anyway and I do have a work around but I'm sure I've seen a way to 'remove' the peroperty somewhere before (perhaps reflection ?)

So the class looks something like this...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Example")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq1", sequenceName = "seq1")
public class Example implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="name", nullable=true, length = 100)
    private java.lang.String name;

    @Column(name="id", nullable=false)      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ1_Type_SEQ")
    @Id
    private long oID;

    @Column(name="extraval", nullable=false, length = 100)
    private java.lang.String entityVersion;4

...
```

And extraVal gets set by various jpa/db constraints if it isn't set in the pojo.  Sometimes I would like to trigger this, even though it has already been set, but setting the value to empty string sets it to a value and setting to null triggers an error.

I can actually simulate the value in advance and I hope to refactor the code at some point so that I can do all my checks before I create the object in the first place so I'm not look to copy/recreate the object etc.  Like I say I'm just sure there is an elegant way to remove the property as a short term solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm just sure there is an elegant way to remove the property as a short term solution ?

There isn't.  It is not possible to modify a class using reflection.

In theory it is possible to modify a compiled class before or while it is being loaded.  However, the chances are that the annotation processor for your JPA framework is already doing that.  So I don't think that would be practical.  (Let alone desirable!)

Comment: Okay I guess I was getting confused about the order of events.  It is possible to create the object without the not null field but I guess it is 'autopopulated' at this point not on persist (I kind of thought I was trying to remove it from the obect (an imaginary way of setting a non nullable field to null!) rather than the class but on reflection I see what you are saying is true, I would be removing it from the class itself.  Thanks.